# Typed Racket, type matching not working for me

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I need this input `(board-ref (Game-board new-game) (Pos 3 4))` to come out true. I've run through the function step by step and it seems like it should come out true, but for some reason, it keeps coming up false? Can anyone help me fix this? Thanks.

```lisp
(define-type Player (U 'black 'white))

(define-struct Pos
  ([row : Integer]  ;; an integer on the interval [0,7]
   [col : Integer]) ;; an integer on the interval [0,7]
  #:transparent)

(define-struct Board
  ([squares : (Listof (U Player 'none))]) ;; a list of length 64
  #:transparent)

(define-struct Game
  ([board : Board]
   [next  : Player])
  #:transparent)

(: board-ref : Board Pos -> (U Player 'none))
; Returns the current status of a given position on a given board
(define (board-ref b p)
  (cond
    [(or (< (Pos-row p) 0) (< (Pos-col p) 0)) (error "Negative Position value")]
    [(or (> (Pos-row p) 7) (> (Pos-col p) 7)) (error "Position value too large")]
    [else
     (list-ref
      (Board-squares b)
      (+ (* (Pos-row p) 8) (Pos-col p)))]))


(: outflank-hr : Board Player Pos -> Boolean)
; Tests if player can outflank in horizontal right direction
(define (outflank-hr b pl po)
  (local
    {(: path : Board Player Pos -> Boolean)
     (define (path b pl po)
       (match pl
         ['white
          (match po
            [(Pos r c)
             (match (board-ref b po)
               (error #f)
               ('none #f)
               ('white #t)
               ('black (path b pl (Pos r (+ 1 c)))))])]
         ('black
          (match po
            [(Pos r c)
             (match (board-ref b po)
               (error #f)
               ('none #f)
               ('black #t)
               ('white (path b pl (Pos r (+ 1 c)))))]))))}
    (match (board-ref b po)
      [Player #f]
      ['none
       (match pl
         ['black
          [match po
            [(Pos r c)
             (match (board-ref b (Pos r (+ c 1)))
               ['none #f]
               ['black #f]
               ['white (path b 'black (Pos r (+ c 1)))])]]]
         ['white
          [match po
            [(Pos r c)
             (match (board-ref b (Pos r (+ c 1)))
               ['none #f]
               ['white #f]
               ['black (path b 'white (Pos r (+ c 1)))])]]])])))
```

Comment: How are your Board and Pos types defined? What game is this and what are it's rules? Also, does the `path` function have to be defined within the `outflank-hr` definition? They don't seem to share variables, and if you move it out you can take advantage of the `define/match` shorthand to make your code much cleaner and shorter

Comment: This is a computer version of the board game Othello.

Comment: Based on the output you're matching against when you use `board-ref` other places, shouldn't the output for `(board-ref (Game-board new-game) (Pos 3 4))` be `'none`, since the starting Othello board is empty at row 3 column 4?

Comment: Also, you'll want to include your definition of `board-ref`, so we can check that there's nothing strange happening there

Comment: No the starting board has black pieces at (row 3, col 4) and (row 4, col 3) and white pieces at (row 3, col 3) and (row 4, col 4).

Comment: My bad, didn't notice your board indices start at 0 while Wikipedia's start at 1. So you expect `(outflank-hr (Game-board new-game) 'white (Pos 3 4))` to evaluate to `#t`?